# Digit image getting predicted differently

Tags: python, knn, image-classification

[image]

The above *8* figure is getting predicted as *2* whereas the following 8 is getting predicted properly as *8*.

[image]

I am not sure what could be making these two quite similar images getting predicted differently with the same model.

My model is built using the `KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=30)` with MNIST training dataset that contains 28x28 samples

Comment: You can try tuning the n_neighbors argument for your model. Some mis-predictions will usually happen in ML models which can be minimized by changing model parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can always be few exceptions that your machine learning model won't predict correctly. You can always try different values for the parameters to find the best model for your problem set.

However, for this problem (classification of handwritten digits ), I suggest you use neural networks for better accuracy.